# AWS S3Client putObject() Exception: Connection Pool Time Out

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am seeing this stack trace in my spring boot project some time after I deploy to my servers. Everytime I restart Spring boot, the error disappears then reappears after a while:

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException: Timeout waiting for connection from pool
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$1.get(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:282)
        at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor51.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70)
        at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy130.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:190)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1346)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)
        ... 73 more
```

I suspect some client of leakage is happening where connections are not being released after being used. Here is how I am setting up my S3Client object:

```
@Bean
public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client(){
    // Create a ClientConfiguration object to configure the S3 client
    ClientConfiguration clientConfig = new ClientConfiguration();

    // Set the maximum number of open HTTP connections (connection pool size)
    clientConfig.setMaxConnections(500); // Set your desired pool size here
    clientConfig.setConnectionTimeout(10000); // 15 seconds

    Regions clientRegion = Regions.US_EAST_1;

    AppConfig config = appConfigRepository.findAll().get(0);

    String accessKey = config.getAmazonS3AccessKey();
    String secretKey = config.getAmazonS3SecretKey();

    //This code expects that you have AWS credentials set up per:
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-credentials.html
    // Create AWS Basic Credentials
    BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

    // Configure the S3 client builder
    AmazonS3ClientBuilder clientBuilder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
            .withClientConfiguration(clientConfig)
            .withRegion(clientRegion);

    // Build the S3 client
    return clientBuilder.build();
}
```

I then use this one object to upload images using the putObject method here:

```
try (ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes)) {
    s3Client.putObject(bucketName, imagePath, inputStream, metadata);
}
```

I tried increasing the size of the connection pool from the default (I believe it was 50) to 500. This had the effect of increasing the time it takes from restarting my spring boot project to the exception occurring. I also tried using a try with resources block incase somehow leaking my byteArray was an issue - this had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code base is very old and is not best practice. Instead of using V1, you should be using the lastest ***AWS S3 Java V2*** libs and use [Async calls](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/asynchronous.html) (non blocking). I will provide you a path to best practice S3 Java code.

To upload content to S3, strongly consider using the [AWS Transfer Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/transfer-manager.html).

For example, assume you want to upload a stream (binary data that is mp3 for example). In your example, that seems to be what you are attempting to do.

You can use this Async way with Transfer Manager to efficienty upload a data stream. Its very clean and represents best practice.

```
package org.example;

import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.AsyncRequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.core.async.BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody;
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3AsyncClient;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.S3TransferManager;
import software.amazon.awssdk.transfer.s3.model.Upload;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;



public class Main {

    private static S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient;

    private static synchronized S3AsyncClient getS3AsyncClient() {
        if (s3AsyncClient == null) {
            s3AsyncClient = S3AsyncClient.crtBuilder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .build();
        }
        return s3AsyncClient;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


        System.out.println("This shows how to use the S3TransferManager to upload a file to S3!");
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\AWS\\output.mp3");

        String key = putAudio(is, "scottpolicytestbucket2", "output.mp3");
        System.out.println(key + " has been uploaded to S3!");

    }

    public static String putAudio(InputStream is, String bucketName, String key) throws S3Exception, IOException {
        try {
            S3TransferManager transferManager = S3TransferManager.builder()
                .s3Client(getS3AsyncClient())
                .build();

            BlockingInputStreamAsyncRequestBody body = AsyncRequestBody.forBlockingInputStream(null); // 'null' indicates a stream will be provided later.
            Upload upload = transferManager.upload(builder -> builder
                .requestBody(body)
                .putObjectRequest(req -> req.bucket(bucketName).key(key))
                .build());

            body.writeInputStream(is);
            upload.completionFuture().join();
            return key;

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

You can find more examples for Transfer Manager in AWS Code Repo Github here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/transfermanager

**Update**

Here is a full example POM that works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>S3MavenTransferManager</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.45</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>apache-client</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk.crt</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-crt</artifactId>
            <version>0.25.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-1.2-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>textract</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3control</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>translate</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>comprehend</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>polly</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-booter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>lambda</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3-transfer-manager</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am trying to implement this but running into some dependency problems caused by the CRT module. The .crtBuilder() method is throwing  the following exception:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load classes from AWS Common Runtime (CRT) library.software.amazon.awssdk.crt:crt is a required dependency; make sure you have it on the classpath.

However when I use the builder() method it works fine (booting up the project) but fails to upload a multipart file. I believe I am including all of the correct gradle dependencies. CRT should come with SDK.

Comment: For gradle -- use this implementation group: 'software.amazon.awssdk.crt', name: 'aws-crt', version: '0.25.1' and implementation group: 'software.amazon.awssdk', name: 's3-transfer-manager', version: '2.20.26'

Comment: I tested the above Java code with the POM - it works

Comment: Glad it works. That’s best way to upload streams to S3 via java!